# Sorting Data in Oracle Table using 2 Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table called jobs. In this table, I have 2 jobs, JOB 1 and JOB 2. I need get one job based on the following conditions.

1. The `IS_ASSIST JOB_PROCESS` must have a `JOB_PROCESS_STATE = '0'`. This is satisfied by both `JOB` 1 and 2.
2. If both jobs' `IS_ASSIST` has a state of 0, then get the job that has a `JOB_PROCESS = IS_PULLAHEAD` and `JOB_PROCESS_STATE = 1`.

This should get the last row with `ID = 4`. How would I write these conditions in a query? Here is an example which only applies the first condition. How would I also apply the second condition?

```
SELECT JOB_ID 
FROM JOB 
WHERE JOB_PROCESS = 'IS_ASSIST' 
AND JOB_PROCESS_STATE = '0'
```

JOB Table:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|ID |JOB_ID|  JOB_PROCESS |JOB_PROCESS_STATE|
+-------------------------------------------+
| 1 |  1   |   IS_ASSIST  |      0          |
|-------------------------------------------|
| 2 |  1   | IS_PULLAHEAD |      0          |
|-------------------------------------------|
| 3 |  2   |   IS_ASSIST  |      0          |
|-------------------------------------------|
| 4 |  2   | IS_PULLAHEAD |      1          |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the first record from this query

```
select JOB_ID
from JOB
where JOB_ID IN
(
  SELECT JOB_ID 
  FROM JOB
  WHERE JOB_PROCESS = 'IS_ASSIST' AND JOB_PROCESS_STATE = '0'
  GROUP BY JOB_ID
)
ORDER BY case when JOB_PROCESS = IS_PULLAHEAD AND JOB_PROCESS_STATE = 1 
              then 0
              else 1 
         end
```